# SVN automatic merge from trunk to branch by specifying JIRA ticket id

Tags: svn, merge, jira

I use JIRA as bug-tracking system. If there is a newly revealed bug then it is commited to the trunk first. Commits are done under a specific ticket. 
For example, ticket #37 is fixed by commits: 65, 68 and 74.

Sometimes I would need to backport a ticket to a branch. So I have to download a repository for a branch, i.e. #3 and apply following command

```
svn merge -c65,68,74  http://.../svn/trunk
```

then to commit and so on for every ticket.

What I would like to do is specify a list of tickets from JIRA and branch id. So they would be merged automatically from trunk to a specific branch.

What are the options to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referencing your Jira tickets in a consistent way from the commit messages, using the Jira ABC-123 ticket number format you can get a list of revisions by searching the SVN log.

```
svn log --search=FOO-57 http://.../svn/trunk
```

This will give you the log messages and revision numbers for each relevant commit. Assuming a unix-like environment, you can use some pipes and shell manipulation to convert the svn log output to a list of revision numbers like so:

```
svn log --search=FOO-57 http://.../svn/trunk | grep ^r | cut '-d|' -f1 | sed s,r,,
```

A little bit more shell manipulation can give you that same revision list in a comma-separated format:

```
REVISIONS=($(svn log --search=FOO-57 http://.../svn/trunk | grep ^r | cut '-d|' -f1 | sed s,r,,))
echo "${REVISIONS[*]}" | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

So now you can merge just by using the output of that second command as your `-c` argument to `svn merge`

```
REVISIONS=($(svn log --search=FOO-57 http://.../svn/trunk | grep ^r | cut '-d|' -f1 | sed s,r,,))
svn merge -c$(echo "${REVISIONS[*]}" | sed 's/ /,/g') http://.../svn/trunk
```

You can convert the above into a re-usable shell script by replacing the search term and the URL with `"$1"` and `"$2"`. Or, if you want to apply this to multiple Jira tickets at once, you can wrap the entire thing in a loop like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
TRUNK_URL="http://.../svn/trunk"
REVISIONS=($((for search_term in "$@"; do
    svn log --search="$search_term" "$TRUNK_URL" | grep ^r | cut '-d|' -f1 | sed s,r,,;
done) | sort -u))
svn merge -c$(echo "${REVISIONS[*]}" | sed 's/ /,/g') "$TRUNK_URL"
```

---

If you'd prefer to avoid shell scripting to get the revision list, you can achieve a similar results using any language with `libsvn` bindings. Here's an example using Python and [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pysvn
logs = pysvn.Client().log('http://.../svn/trunk')
to_merge = { x['revision'].number for x in logs if 'FOO-57' in x['message'] }
```

Comment: a more generic approach?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov more generic in what way? If you mean platform-agnostic, the same basic approach can be achieved in any language that can work with I/O pipes, as all I'm doing is manipulating STDOUT and command line arguments.

Comment: using JIRA and SVN API, not grep, sed and so on hacks.

Comment: The Jira API is unlikely to give you anything useful unless you're storing revision numbers in a field in Jira somewhere. You can use libsvn bindings to search through SVN log messages for ticket numbers; i've updated the answer with an example of this in Python.